# Four variable boolean algebra simplification

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm having trouble simplifying this expression further strictly with Boolean identities. However, using algorithmic simplifiers I've found that it's possible to simplify it further. Would anyone be able to help? I'm looking for the minimal form of the boolean function. Thanks in advance. (+ is OR, multiplication is AND and ! is NOT)

F = (!A!B!C) + (!A(B)!D) + (A(!B)D) + (!A(C)D) + (AB!C)

Actual simplest form: (!A!B!D) + (AB!C) + (!B(D)) + (!A(BC))

Comment: How do you measure the function's simplicity?

Comment: I suppose the proper wording for it would be the minimal form of the function. I'll replace this in the main question now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You could make Venn diagram where AND corresponds with intersection, OR with union and NOT with complement.

Comment: Speaking of algebraic methods, it is possible to find reduced DNF first and get the desired minimal DNF just by deleting some of the terms from reduced DNF.

Comment: Why are some terms within parentheses and others not?